# How to automatically calculate tikz shift within pagenodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to correctly align a `tikzpicture` consisting of text inside an arrow that I put in the footer. My problem is that I want the arrow tip aligned with the eastern edge of the footer **and** I want the baseline of the text to align with the rest of the text in the other parts of the footer.

None of the anchoring options seem to yield what I want. If I use the `base east` anchor, the text is correctly aligned but the arrowhead sticks out into the margin, as shown here:

[image: With anchor=base east]

I'm aware of how to add a manual shift. In the MWE below, I have a more or less working solution by using `yshift` to pull the arrow up to the right place, but the value is one that I determined by eyeballing it. That solution looks like this:

[image]

However, it's obviously only valid for this one size. Is there a way to have `tikz` calculate the shift automatically?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{red}}

% This version correctly aligns the CONTINUE text to the baseline,
% but the arrow head sticks out into the margin.
\newcommand{\ContinueNotice}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, font={\large\sffamily\bfseries}]
        \node[single arrow,single arrow head extend=3pt,fill=black,text=white,anchor=base east]
        at (current page footer area.south east) {\enspace CONTINUE\enspace};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

% This version is more or less correctly aligned, but the yshift is done by eye.
\newcommand{\ContinueNoticeAlt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, font={\large\sffamily\bfseries}]
        \node[single arrow,single arrow head extend=3pt,fill=black,text=white,anchor=east,yshift=-2pt]
        at (current page footer area.east) {\enspace CONTINUE\enspace};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\makepagestyle{TestStyle}
\makeoddfoot{TestStyle}{\footnotesize Some Notice}{\thepage}{\ContinueNotice}
\makeevenfoot{TestStyle}{\footnotesize Some Notice}{\thepage}{\ContinueNoticeAlt}
\pagestyle{TestStyle}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `anchor=east` or `left` for the nodes. Name the nodes by eg `n` and use `baseline=(n.base)` as option for the `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{red}}

\newcommand{\ContinueNotice}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, font={\large\sffamily\bfseries},baseline=(n.base)]
        \node[single arrow,single arrow head extend=3pt,fill=black,text=white,left](n)
        at (current page footer area.south east) {\enspace CONTINUE\enspace};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\ContinueNoticeAlt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, font={\large\sffamily\bfseries},baseline=(n.base)]
        \node[single arrow,single arrow head extend=3pt,fill=black,text=white,anchor=east](n)
        at (current page footer area.east) {\enspace CONTINUE\enspace};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\makepagestyle{TestStyle}
\makeoddfoot{TestStyle}{\footnotesize Some Notice}{\thepage}{\ContinueNotice}
\makeevenfoot{TestStyle}{\footnotesize Some Notice}{\thepage}{\ContinueNoticeAlt}
\pagestyle{TestStyle}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Note that there is no need to use `tikzpagenodes` and `remember picture`. Then you have to run it only once.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{red}}

\newcommand{\ContinueNotice}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, font={\large\sffamily\bfseries},baseline=(n.base)]
    \node[single arrow,single arrow head extend=3pt,fill=black,text=white,left](n)
      {\enspace CONTINUE\enspace};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\ContinueNoticeAlt}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, font={\large\sffamily\bfseries},baseline=(n.base)]
    \node[single arrow,single arrow head extend=3pt,fill=black,text=white,anchor=east](n)
      {\enspace CONTINUE\enspace};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\makepagestyle{TestStyle}
\makeoddfoot{TestStyle}{\footnotesize Some Notice}{\thepage}{\ContinueNotice}
\makeevenfoot{TestStyle}{\footnotesize Some Notice}{\thepage}{\ContinueNoticeAlt}
\pagestyle{TestStyle}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: This does exactly what I want, so thanks. I have an additional question, though, merely out of curiosity. When I run your version through TexStudio, it takes 6 iterations of pdflatex before it stops. I'm used to 2 or 3 runs to get everything to settle down, but 6 seems supererogatory. Do you know what's happening to cause so many iterations?

Comment: I have added a version without `tikzpagenodes` and without option `remember picture`. Then have to run it only once.